# Encoding categorical features in Python with Encoders

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, encoding, data-science

Can someone, basically tell me the differences between these 3 encoders below, in which cases we use them, and how to write code to use them in a simple way ( with coding in Python sklearn if possible )

I am having quite difficult time to get to know the logic behind them in sklearn therefore I decided to ask in here.

- One-Hot Encoding
- Ordinal Encoding
- Label Encoding

Thanks for your responses and helps

Happy coding

Comment: This is a very open ended question for this site. You should be able to good answers with a search. For example, one-hot-encoding is nicely explained [here](https://hackernoon.com/what-is-one-hot-encoding-why-and-when-do-you-have-to-use-it-e3c6186d008f)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that -

- OrdinalEncoder - will assign a number to categorical X variables
- LabelEncoder - will assign a number to categorical Y variables
- OneHotEncoder - will create a separate "column" for each category of each X variable

For example - let's take the example from the `sklearn` docs -

```py
import numpy as np
import random
browser_choice = ["uses Firefox", "uses Chrome", "uses Safari", "uses Internet Explorer"]
x_values_train = np.array([[_] for _ in browser_choice])
x_values_test = np.array([["uses Chrome"], ["uses Safari"]])
```

So, your training dataset contains 4 values of `browser_choice` while your test dataset contains just 2 of them

**Ordinal Encoding**

```py
ord_enc = OrdinalEncoder()
ord_enc.fit(x_values_train)
ord_enc.transform(x_values_test)
```

*Output*

```
array([[0.],
       [3.]])
```

You'll notice that it has assigned a value of `0` to `"uses Chrome"` and `3` to `"uses Safari"`.

**One Hot Encoding**

```py
ohe_enc = OneHotEncoder()
ohe_enc.fit(x_values_train)
pd.DataFrame(ohe_enc.transform(x_values_test).toarray(), columns=ohe_enc.categories_)
```

*Output*

```
  uses Chrome uses Firefox uses Internet Explorer uses Safari
0         1.0          0.0                    0.0         0.0
1         0.0          0.0                    0.0         1.0
```

The `pandas.DataFrame` is not really required, but what it shows you is that we now have 4 columns - and the "uses Chrome" now corresponds to a `1` in the `"uses Chrome"` column and "uses Safari" corresponds to a `1` in the `"uses Safari"` column - only one of these 4 columns would have a `1` in them for each row

**Label Encoding** can be thought of as Ordinal Encoding for the y variable and I am leaving it out of the explanation here.

Comment: There's a longer explanation of the differences between `ordinal` and `label` encoders [in here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/39317/difference-between-ordinalencoder-and-labelencoder?newreg=4fcd695eb02345639d6c6892ea8e2bd6) as well.